# DotNetOpenAuth OAuth 2.0 authorization with Google

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I am trying to use DNOA to connect with Facebook and Google over OAuth 2.0.

The same code is working with Facebook, but isn't working with Google

```
IAuthorizationState authorization = client.ProcessUserAuthorization(request);
if (authorization == null) {
    // Kick off authorization request
    client.RequestUserAuthorization(openAuthClient.scope, new Uri(redirectUrl));
}
```

The question is why?

I start logging DNOA request and found following:

```
2014-03-27 12:20:19,497 (GMT+9) [6] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send AccessTokenAuthorizationCodeRequestC (2.0) message.

2014-03-27 12:20:19,500 (GMT+9) [6] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing AccessTokenAuthorizationCodeRequestC (2.0) message for https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: 

code: 4/sFMRXFQwkQR_I1BsKXIA-XRO0eid.MoM8z1Q_qZEdPvB8fYmgkJxxjiYDigI
redirect_uri: http://test.almazcom.ru/asp/logon.aspx?Mode=OpenAuthLogon&Provider=google&Response=1&authuser=0&num_sessions=1&session_state=f1b3dbc278071954a1b03facd6d7053deac831f7..b3c2&prompt=none
grant_type: authorization_code
client_id: 514202796818.apps.googleusercontent.com
client_secret: ********

2014-03-27 12:20:19,500 (GMT+9) [6] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending AccessTokenAuthorizationCodeRequestC request.

2014-03-27 12:20:20,447 (GMT+9) [6] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - HTTP POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

2014-03-27 12:20:20,533 (GMT+9) [6] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.Http - https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token returned 400 BadRequest: Bad Request

2014-03-27 12:20:20,533 (GMT+9) [6] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - WebException from https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: 
{
"error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

Then I change parameter redirect_uri and send this request manually. Result is OK! In my Google application specified following redirect uri: http://test.almazcom.ru/asp/logon.aspx?Mode=OpenAuthLogon&Provider=google&Response=1

How can I change uri during user authorization (method ProcessUserAuthorization) with  different one? This uri must be exactly same as Google application Redirect URI. In other cases I get "invalid_request" from Google

Comment: Does not anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the "state" to store information on post authentication redirects

To stop DNOA setting a state automatically and allowing you to set your own one create a implementation of IClientAuthorizationTracker

```
Public Class TokenManager
 Implements IClientAuthorizationTracker

 Function GetAuthorizationState(callbackUrl As System.Uri, clientState As String) As IAuthorizationState Implements IClientAuthorizationTracker.GetAuthorizationState
  Dim oAS As AuthorizationState = Nothing
            If True Then
                oAS = New AuthorizationState()
                oAS.Callback = callbackUrl
            End If
        Return oAS
    End Function
End Class
```

and then

```
oClient = New WebServerClient(MyAuthDesc)
...
oClient.AuthorizationTracker = New TokenManager
```

lastly (When ProcessUserAuthorization() returns Null/Nothing)

```
Dim owr As DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.OutgoingWebResponse
owr = oClient.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(scopes:=sScope, returnTo:=Request.Url) 
oOAuthParams.Redirect = owr.Headers.Item("Location") & "&state=" & sReturnHere
```

When ProcessUserAuthorization succeeds and you verify your access token then you can read the state in the URL and do something with it (I do not use it to return I actually use it to discourage fraud)

I needed to do the above anyway to get DNOA working as I did not want to use the session object

Hope this helps.