# Facebook DotNetOpenAuth Unexpected OAuth authorization response received

Tags: c#, facebook, dotnetopenauth, facebook-oauth

Trying to use DotNetOpenAuth to create a login with Facebook feature but I keep getting this
error message when the callback is reached

```
Unexpected OAuth authorization response received with callback and client state that does not match an expected value.
```

Cant figure out what is going on here it happens when it hits `ProcessUserAuthorization`
Does anyone have any tips on how to debug what is happening here. I tried checking fiddler
and my MVC session and DNOA XSRF stay the same between both calls.

Haven't seen too many examples of people getting past this issue or using DNOA with facebook in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link.

[DotNetOpenAuth OAuth 2.0 authorization with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677983/dotnetopenauth-oauth-2-0-authorization-with-google)

DNOA messes around with the Session and if you don't use a session it makes the state random (and thus you get your error message).